# HTML5 Canvas: Bezier curve to draw on load

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have draw the Bezier Curve. But I Want Animate the Bezier Curve in onload for 1 time.

Please help me..

Here the below code:

```js
   window.onload = function() {
    
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var x=10, y=25;
    
    function curve() {
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(214, 0);
      context.bezierCurveTo(328, 80, 153, 82, 216, 162);
      context.lineWidth = 10;
      context.strokeStyle = 'gray';
      context.stroke();
     }
    
    curve();
    
    };
```

```html
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300" style="text-align: left; border: 1px solid black; position: absolute; left: 100px;"></canvas>
</body>
```

Curve draw on 0 to (328, 80, 153, 82, 216, 162)

Comment: Animate in what fashion?

Comment: Animate in snake movement is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cheat to get the effect, although the animation does not bend according to the line 
(you have to stop the timer and this might not work if there are other drawn object near it)

http://jsfiddle.net/o9k83k0g/

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var x=10, y=25;
var show=0;    

function curve() {
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(214, 0);
  context.bezierCurveTo(328, 80, 153, 82, 216, 162);
  context.lineWidth = 10;
  context.strokeStyle = 'gray';
  context.stroke();

  context.beginPath();   
  context.fillStyle = 'white';
  context.fillRect(160,0+show,100,175-show);
  context.stroke();
  show=show+1;
 }
setInterval(function(){curve();}, 30);
```

Comment: Sorry to say..I need fill style "transparent" Is it Possible or not..?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to animate the curve, you can structurate your code like that :

```
var snake = {
    points:[ {x:100,y:100},{x:100,y:150},{x:100,y:200},{x:100,y:250} ]
}

function loop(){
    physic( snake )
    display( snake )
}
setInterval( loop, 20 )
```

In the physic function, you update points in the snake structure according to what you want.
In the display function you do something like that :

```
function display( snake ){

    var point = snake.points[0];

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    ctx.moveTo( point.x, point.y );

    for( i=0; i< snake.points.length-1; i++ ){

        point = snake.points[i];

        var xc = (point.x + snake.points[i + 1].x) / 2;
        var yc = (point.y + snake.points[i + 1].y) / 2;

        ctx.quadraticCurveTo( point.x, point.y, xc, yc );
    }

    ctx.stroke();
}
```

The difficult part is the physic function.

```
function physic( snake ){

    snake.points[2].x++ // An example
}
```

Comment: Thanks for support....but really Sorry...i need to Bezier Curve but to here declared Quadratic Curve...and one more physic(snake) this function is not working...

Comment: This is just an example. You can easly replace quadraticCurveTo by a Bezier curve in the display function.